# Setting IIS config via appcmd.exe for Load User Profile

Tags: iis, powershell, appcmd

I am attempting to set the config setting for 'Load User Profile' to true via a powershell script using appcmd.exe.  After reading through many documents I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

The app pool's name is like 'accountsmanagement.example.com'  I have tried variations on the following but all error out:

```
c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:applicationPools /accountsmanagement.example.com.processModel.loadUserProfile:true
```

How do I correctly set the Load User Profile to true via appcmd.exe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this with quotes.

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:applicationPools "/[name='accountsmanagement.example.com'].processModel.loadUserProfile:false"
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer set the setting to _false_? The Original Poster wanted the opposite.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to purely use `PowerShell` you can use the following `PowerShell` command to change the 'Load User Profile' property of an application pool.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\YourAppPoolName" -Name "processModel.loadUserProfile" -Value "False"
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for sharing this. Works since Win2008 / IIS 7.

Comment: FYI: WebAdministration module: `Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data.` trying to set config from appcmd.exe also requires elavation though. As they should

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `appcmd.exe set config` you can also use the following

```
appcmd.exe set apppool "App Pool name here" -processmodel.loaduserprofile:"true"
```

To show all values that can be set use

```
appcmd.exe set apppool "App Pool name here" /?
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!